# Can't get access to other database

Tags: mysql, errors, permissions

I am working on a project for my university. They gave me a login username and password for `MySQL` database they've setup on the server.

With that username and password, I'm able to login to the server. I ran the following query on it:

```
SHOW GRANTS;
```

And got following output

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'me'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*mypass'
```

Now if I am trying to create a database with following code

```
CREATE DATABASE test;
```

I am getting following error

> ```
> Error: 1044
> Access denied for user 'me'@'localhost' to database 'test'
> ```

As far as I know, *.* means access to all tables of all databases. Where is the problem. Please help me to rectify me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please `RUN` the following:

```
select user();
select current_user();
```

The former is who you are attempting to login as; the second is what the database sees as connected. You will need to run `grant_priv` to user.

Here is how to verify:

```
mysql> SELECT host,user,password,Grant_priv,Super_priv FROM mysql.user
```

If the `grant_priv` is set to 'N' for your user, this needs to be 'Y'.

To grant access you can run:

```
UPDATE mysql.user 
SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' 
WHERE User='me'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'me'@'localhost'
```

Comment: For both `select user()` & `select current_user()` I am getting same output `me@localhost`. But for the second query, I am getting `SELECT command denied to user 'me'@'localhost' for table 'user'`

Comment: And for the last 3 queries, I am getting error **1064**, **1227** and **1045**

Answer (score 1):

As the [MySQL's documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_usage) says:

> The USAGE privilege specifier stands for “no privileges.” It is used
>   at the global level with GRANT to modify account attributes such as
>   resource limits or SSL characteristics without affecting existing
>   account privileges.

**Test:**

```
mysql> GRANT USAGE ON test.* TO 'me'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT CURRENT_USER();
+----------------+
| CURRENT_USER() |
+----------------+
| me@localhost   |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE test2;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'me'@'localhost' to database 'test2'
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what you did, you should run the following:

`GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'me'@'localhost'`

[More about GRANT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html)

Creating users and granting permissions can be done in more one way. One of them is `GRANT USAGE....`. If you instead to create a user using [CREATE USER Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-user.html), and then run `SHOW PRIVILEGES FOR 'user'@'host'`, you will notice that the user has `USAGE ON *.*`.

All that to say that you need to grant permissions after adding the user, regardless of how the user was added.